# Is there any way to add a template doc at top of an another google document using google scripting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a template doc into an existing google doc.The template is being added, but next time when i am trying to add the template again the template is appending at the bottom of the existing google doc but i want to insert the template at the top.

You can do this by getting the Body of one document and appending its child Elements to the current document.

```
function addtemplate() {

  var thisDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var thisBody = thisDoc.getBody();

  var templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById(''); //Pass in id of doc to be used as a template.
  var templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();

  for(var i=0; i<templateBody.getNumChildren();i++){ //run through the elements of the template doc's Body.
    switch (templateBody.getChild(i).getType()) { //Deal with the various types of Elements we will encounter and append.
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH:
        thisBody.appendParagraph(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM:
        thisBody.appendListItem(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
      case DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE:
        thisBody.appendTable(templateBody.getChild(i).copy());
        break;
    }
  }

  return thisDoc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your goal is to choose the position of the document where the content is added?

One option is to add the template at your current cursor location.

In the example below I have two functions.  The first function creates a menu in Google Docs when I open the document (usually a few seconds delay).

The second function attempts to identify the position of my cursor.  If it's successful it will insert the date at my cursor position.

Since I've created a menu item I don't have to go to the script editor to trigger this function.

```
function onOpen() {
  // Add a menu item in Google Docs.
  DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('Insert Menu')
      .addItem('Insert Current Date', 'insertCurrentDate')
      .addToUi();
}

function insertCurrentDate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  if (cursor) {
    // Attempt to insert text at the cursor position. If insertion returns null,
    // then the cursor's containing element doesn't allow text insertions.
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var element = cursor.insertText(date);
    if (element) {
      element.setBold(true);
    } else {
      DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Document does not allow inserted text at this location.');
    }
  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

It's also possible that you want to clear the previous template before pasting the new one in?  You can do that with the clear() function and then run the rest of your code.

```
body.clear()
```